# How to fix the header of GridView

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a GridView in ASP.NET page with 1000+ records along with header putted grid view in div. When I'm scrolling, GridView header also moving up because of the I am not able to view the header information. Please let me know any solution for fixing header.

Comment: Use [IdeaSparks CoolGridView](http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/releases/view/37905)(MIT License)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use a third-party control to achieve this, you can do it with CSS.

The HTML generated by asp.net is not totally standard, you first need to alter a bit how the table will be rendered in order to generated a `<thead>`. Add these lines after the databinding:

```
MyGridView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
MyGridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

There are tons of tutorials that explain how to make your table content scrollable with fixed content. Found and quickly tested this one: [How to add a fixed table header with a vertical scrollbar in content](http://encolpe.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/how-to-add-a-fixed-table-header-with-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-content/).

I would change one thing though:

```
div.tableContainer {
   ...
   // instead of overflow: auto
   // even though it is a CSS3 property, it has been widely supported for a long time (IE5+, FF1.5+, O9.5+, Safari3+, Chrome2+)
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
   ...
}
```